# I don't find the LaTeX command for these symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

[image]
The `\gamma` like symbol. I searched this in http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html but not found.

Comment: `\gamma` is what you want?

Comment: @Sigur: I think it is more of a special type of `\gamma` here... the shown symbol looks more rounded and slanted/italic

Comment: I think the font is the key point.

Comment: The `\mathcal{Q}` is similar to the one from `times` package. But with that the `\gamma` is completely different.

Comment: `\mathcal{F}`? which one exactly?

Comment: @Johannes_B `\mathcal{F}` results exactly.

Comment: `\gamma` from the `mtpro2` package (a Times Roman clone) comes very very close -- and the `\mathcal{Q}` and `\mathcal{F}` characters look right too.

Comment: @alhelal: `\mathcal{F}` does not really look like Γ .... your question is confusing, since there is a γ in the picture as well

Comment: Since i get `\mathcal{F}` from DeTeXify, i guess this question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/H99n2mq.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't ask for `\mathcal{F}` I ask for gamma

Comment: @alhelal, so your question was not clear. In title you wrote *these* but you want for a single symbol.

Comment: @alhelal Why not simply crop the image to the symbold your interested in? Or mark it? Like this its really confusing!

Comment: @Sigur I mention gamma like.

Comment: @alhelal, so, *gamma like* is not correct. It is *F like*.

Comment: @Sigur I don't understand why people see only `\mathcal{F}`. See starting symbol of my image.

Comment: @alhelal, so why you wrote *`\mathcal{F}` results exactly*. For me it means that you wished *F*.

Comment: @Sigur as Johannes_B said `\mathcal{F}?`, so I told him that it is not, it works well. As you noticed that comment you should understand that I didn't ask for that as it works well.

Comment: A gamma is a gamma; some fonts render it one way, others in a slightly different form. Don't worry and use the one provided by `\gamma`.

Comment: There are three votes to reopen this question, probably because there is a good answer. But the question as it is, is not worth of reopening before it has been edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Times Roman text font package (e.g., `newtxtext`) along with the [MathTime Professional 2](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) math font package (aka `mtpro2`) will give you the `\gamma`, `\mathcal{Q}`, and `\mathcal{F}` glyphs shown in your screenshot. The curly brace, though, looks *much fancier* -- it's almost sumptuous -- than the corresponding, rather spindly and sad-looking brace in your screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\gamma_{\mathrm{ub}}(\mathcal{Q})=
\begin{cases}
f(\mathbf{c}_{\min}), & \mathbf{c}_{\min}\in\mathcal{F}\\
+\infty,               & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mtpro2.sty` not found.

Comment: @alhelal - Did you follow the link I provided? The complete `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge. However, its `lite` subset, which is all that's needed to produce the screenshot shown above, may be downloaded free of charge.

Comment: @Mico, that should be a miracle....

Comment: @Mico Do you say to me installing some thing?

Comment: @alhelal - I interpreted your question as asking for a math font (package) that provides an exact match for the `\gamma` symbol. My answer, I believe, provides such a match. Since `mtpro2` isn't a font package that's automatically included with the main TeX distributions, I provided a link to the website from which one may download this math font package. I honestly have no expectations for what you will do with this information. Aside: Downloading and installing this font package (and especially its `lite` subset) is no more difficult than installing virtually any other package is.